# Failure to send data ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This my jQuery code:

```
$("li").on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/ads/updateads", // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: {name: 'mhf'}, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
        contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
        cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
        processData: false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
        success: function (data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            $('body').append('Errrrrrror');
        }
    });
});
```

and my php code is here:

```
 <?php
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

and html code:

```
<ul id="myselect">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

but $_POST is empty, please tell me where is wrong?

Comment: `processData: false,` | `_ contentType: false`

Comment: You should not need to use contentType or processData. You should add a dataType, like dataType: 'json'. In PHP, you should only echo json_encode( $_POST ); Also, if it was me, I'd put single quotes around "name" in your post data object.

Comment: Thanks **@Brian**, but when i use exactly the same code in my form Works correctly but here i don't know!  can you explain me more?

Comment: I think when you are doing ajax, unless you specifically need something, it's better to keep the settings lite. Just populate the `type`, `url`, `data`, `success`, and `error`. Also,I would maybe make the url super literal `/ads/updateads/index.php` so you know for sure it's not some weird routing thing. Rule out all the basic stuff....

Comment: You get no console/network messages in the browser developer tools ?

Comment: No **@Steve**, no messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> The data option can contain either a query string of the form
>   key1=value1&key2=value2, or an object of the form {key1: 'value1',
>   key2: 'value2'}. If the latter form is used, the data is converted
>   into a query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent. This
>   processing can be **circumvented by setting processData to false**.